# How to make a Regex researcher with asterisk

Tags: regex

Does anybody know how to make a Regex researcher with asterisk character as in windows OS?

Example: *.pdf -> Find all pdf  files.

I've been trying with this snippet but I' not quite sure if It is quite strong:

```
   FTP.FTPclient ftp = new FTP.FTPclient("ftp://myservices.com/","username", "pass");
            Regex reg = new Regex(@"Hi");
            string[] filesArray = ftp.ListDirectory("/path/").Where(fileName => reg.IsMatch(fileName)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Are you talking about searching a file structure in C# to find files using a Regex search term?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `*.pdf`, try using `(.*)pdf`. In other words, replace `*` with `(.*)` and see if it works.

Comment: Hi, anda how Can I  replace pdf with a input string? Example: Regex reg = new Regex(@"(.*)Pdf"); ---> Regex reg = new Regex(@"(.*)MyInputString");

Comment: Hi, Bruno. Instead of creating a Regex object, simply use the static method, Regex.IsMatch(). Simply pass the input string and the pattern string. The method returns a boolean value. Try it out.

Comment: Let's say that the variable MyInputString is the input pattern and the variable MyStringToCheck is the base string. You can do this: Regex.IsMatch(MyStringToCheck, "(.*)" + MyInputString, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Comment: Hi Louie, Thanks for your help. so, I've been trying this, and in some cases it works great, in others do not! For Example: If I run this snippet on Ftp it works , but if I run it on local FileSystem ,it does not respond :  String[] files = Directory.GetFiles(SrcPath).Where(fileName => Regex.IsMatch(fileName, "(.*)" + *.pdf, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)).ToArray()   I Don't knows why when it hits a none pdf file, the compiler crashes!

Comment: Hi, Bruno. Please update the question with a copy of your latest codes. Please also include the error that you're getting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091252/why-linq-query-with-regex-statement-get-locked/16091417?noredirect=1#16091417

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to find any filename having extention pdf

```
.+\.pdf$
```

`.` matches a single character

`+` is a quantifier which matches 1 to many preceding character

---

You can use `GetExtention` method of [path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx) to get the extention of a file

```
ftp.ListDirectory("/path/")
   .Where(Path.GetExtension(fileName)==".pdf")
   .ToArray();
```

---

If you want to check for a particular word within a file's content

```
ftp.ListDirectory("/path/")
   .Where(File.ReadAllText(fileName).Contains(yourWord))
   .ToArray();
```

---

If you want to check for a particular word within a filename

```
ftp.ListDirectory("/path/")
       .Where(fileName.Contains(youWord))
       .ToArray();
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. But want I need to know is How can I Do a search for any kind of  input character. Example: If my input is "Dog", It will retrieve every file that contains "Dog" Or "dog"

Comment: @BrunoFerreia do you want to search within a filename or content of that file

Comment: @BrunoFerreira you don't need regex for that..use Contains method of string..check out the edit

Comment: Thanks so much... How can I retrieve files with both Uppercase and lowerecase characters? Example : "Dog" && "dog"

Comment: @BrunoFerreira you can use `IndexOf` method of String with `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`..So if `fileName.indexOf(yourWord,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)` returns -1 then it's not found!