# why Linq Query with Regex statement get locked

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to filter a search using Regex object bot on fileSytem an Ftp research.
 If I run this snippet on Ftp it works , but if I run it on local FileSystem ,it does not respond :

On FTp

```
string[] filesArray = ftp.ListDirectory(@"/" + SrcPath + @"/").Where(fileName => Regex.IsMatch(fileName, /*@"^[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*?$"*/"(.*)"+ SrcMask, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)).ToArray();
```

On Local FileSystem

```
 String[] files = Directory.GetFiles(SrcPath).Where(fileName => Regex.IsMatch(fileName, "(.*)" + *.pdf, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)).ToArray()
```

Doing the same with a foreach , I notice that when it hits a "none pdf" file, on if condition, the statement get locked:

```
string input = "*.pdf";
Regex regx = new Regex("(.*)"+input); 
String[] filesName = Directory.GetFiles("c:\\temp\\").Select(fileName => new FileInfo(fileName).FullName).ToArray();
foreach(String s  in filesName)
{
    if (regx.IsMatch(s))
    {
        File.Copy(s, "C:\\temp\\files\\"+s.Split('\\').Last(), true);
        count++; 
    }
    Console.WriteLine(count);              
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that

```
(.*)*
```

causes backtracking hell when the regex fails to match.

Get rid of the unnecessary second `*`, or better just use `\.pdf$` for the regex.